# Pandas как добавить название столбцов в первую строку дата фрейма, без промежуточного сохранения в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Нужно добавить название столбцов как первую строку в дата фрейм, без сохранения в файл.
Данные не для выгрузки в exel.

Вот фрейм:

| name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| serg | 6 | 5 | 87 | df |
| ivan | 3 | ef | d | 4 |

```
import pandas as pd

df = df 
    def data(df):
        f = []
        g = []
        x = 2 #Уровень столбца с названиями
        for i in range(0,len(df.columns)):
            g.append(df.columns[i][x])
        for i in range(0,len(df.iloc[1])):
            h = []
            h.append(g[i])
            d = list(df.iloc[:, i])
            for j in d:
                h.append(j)
            f.append(h)
        data = pd.DataFrame(f)
        data = data.T
        return data
```

Добавить в первую строку в dataframe название столбцов.
Ничего лучше этого не придумал, может есть какой-то другой способ быстрее и лучше.

Comment: ничего не понял. первая строка фрейма дожна дублировать названия колонок? а зачем? может вы посвятите в свой глобальный замысел, и этих движений вообще делать не придется?

Comment: df.rename(columns={1: "x", 2: "y", 3: "z", 4: "xz"})

Comment: @strawdog Замысел такой: хочу выгрузить данные в google sheets, но при выгрузке названия колонок (заголовки) не указывается. Так как планируется, что это будет крутиться на серваке, создавать какой-то промежуточный файл крайне не хочется.

Comment: @СергейКох Нужно не переназвать столбцы, а продублировать заголовки в начало таблицы первой строкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

при df:

```
    a    b
0  10  100
1  20  200
2  30  300
```

делаем:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([df.columns.values], columns=df.columns), df], ignore_index=True)
```

получаем df:

```
    a    b
0   a    b
1  10  100
2  20  200
3  30  300
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!
У меня оказался массив с несколькими уровнями заголовков, т.е. над name были ещё уровень из сводных таблиц, поэтому пришлось добавить выбор уровня и получилось. Очень помогло)

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[x[2] for x in df.columns.values]], columns=df.columns), df], ignore_index=True)

Answer (score 0):

А нужно именно первой строкой? Если у вас обработчик всё-равно ориентируется на названия строк (имена строк в индексе), то может разницы и нет и можно просто вот так сделать:

```py
df.loc['name',:] = df.columns
```

Comment: Да, именно первая строка.